# Is it possible to move some commits to another branch when merge is impossible?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new here and hope someone can help me with my (perhaps simple?) git problem:

I made a Commit ( say "1") on my master branch.
Then I made changes in commit "2" on my bugfix branch.

Then I added more commits, "3","4","5","6" that should be on master, but they are on bugfix, where they don't belong.

Merging doesn't seem possible, as "2" should not be on master.

So I have

> (master) 1 
> .............    | 
> (bugfix) 2-3-4-5-6

and I want

> (master) 1-3-4-5-6 
> .............    |
> (bugfix) 2

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic way of resolving it :

```
# bring into master what should have been
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 3 4 5 6

# then rewind bugfix to its original scope
git checkout bugfix
git reset --hard 2
```